# How to run the javascript.js service continuously and monitor its process?

Tags: node.js, linux, socket.io, redhat, putty

I'm a new in RedHat and nodeJS. I have a file: **socketIO.js** on my linux directory. I can run the service with this command:

```
node socketIO.js
```

I can monitor its process from **PuTTY**.
Then I install node-Forever to run the service continuously.

```
npm install forever -g
```

I try to run:

```
forever start socketIO.js
```

The service is running, but I cannot monitor the process. 
So how to run **node socketIO.js** continuously and monitor its process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To monitor process you can use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)